# How to write HTML and CSS code in Node js to Send Eamils to Users

Tags: html, css, node.js, node-cron

I want to send Emails using node-cron and wanted to style the message. Basically, I wanted to send user a list of things as attached below. I wanted to write something like this

```
   <table id="schedule">
      <tr>
        <th>Centre Name</th>
        <th>Vaccine</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>PinCode</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Fee Type</th>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

And I wanted to style these elements of the table. When I tried to write CSS code in Nodejs it showed an error.
How can I do that in node js.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return `
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#f6f6f8" style="background-color:#eeeeee;">
                Some avesome things here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
`
```

Like this

Comment: It's giving Syntax Error !

Comment: Bacially I am using node-cron to send emails. in the 
`var option {`
`from: xyz@gmail.com`
`to : abc@gmail.com`
`subject: 'Hello'`
`text: <I want to write table as shown in Image above>`
`}`

Comment: How can I write it here ? Or I need to do something else. Since I am begineer I have no clue.

Comment: so text must be a string { text: '<div>Some text</div>' }

Comment: Ok, It working now. Also can you please help me how can I fill data in table. Like data is dynamic which I am getting from json file.

Comment: To add any variables to the string you can use string templates
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @PranshuKashyap use handlebars js for dynamic data binding. it is the easiest and clearest way.